# creating Socket to connect to windows 10 machine from Raspberry pi 4 Raspbian does not work (Java)

Tags: java, sockets, networking, windows-10, raspberry-pi4

I have a Raspberry pi 4 with Raspbian installed, and I have a computer with Windows 10 installed.I wrote two functions one send a file and the other one receive the file.
when I run this function that sends a file on the raspberry pi 4:

```
    public static void sendFile(String fileName, String ip)
    {
        BufferedOutputStream outputStream = null;
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        FileInputStream filein = null;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println(fileName + " does not exist");
            return;
        }
        
        try
        {
           Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
           outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
           writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
           reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
           filein = new FileInputStream(file);
           long fileSize = file.length();
           
           writer.println(fileName);        // sending file name
           writer.println(fileSize);   // sending file size in bytes
           writer.flush();
           
           byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
           int numberOfReadBytes = 0;          // the number of read bytes for each read() function call
           System.out.println("Entering the loop");
           for(long i = 0; i < fileSize && numberOfReadBytes > -1;)
           {
               numberOfReadBytes = filein.read(dataBuffer);             // read read() function returns the number of bytes tha has been assigned to the array or -1 if EOF(end of file) is reached
               outputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, numberOfReadBytes);    // writing the bytes in dataBuffer from index 0 to index numberOfBytes
               i += numberOfReadBytes;
           }
           
           outputStream.flush();
           System.out.println(fileName + " sent to " + ip);
           String status = reader.readLine();
           System.out.println("Status: " + status + "\t file save successfully on the other machine.");
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println("Status: 0\n" + ioe.getMessage());
        }
        finally     // closing streams
        {
            try
            {
                outputStream.close();
                reader.close();
                writer.close();
                filein.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                System.err.println("Error closing the connection.");
            }
        }
    }
```

it stops at this line `Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);`

and this is the other function that runs on windows 10

```
    public static void receiveFile()
    {
        // 1- read the file name
        // 2- read the size of the file
        // 3- read the file and write it
        
        ServerSocket server = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        BufferedInputStream inputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream fileout = null;
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        
        try
        {
            server = new ServerSocket(9999);
            socket = server.accept();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            
            String fileName = reader.readLine();                // reading file name
            long fileSize = Long.parseLong(reader.readLine());  // reading file size
            System.out.println(fileSize);

            // reading file data and write the data
            File file = new File(fileName);
            fileout = new FileOutputStream(file);
            
            for (long i = 0; i < fileSize; ++i)
            {
        fileout.write(inputStream.read());
        System.out.println(i);
            }

            fileout.flush();
            fileout.close();
            
            writer.println('1');

        System.out.println("Status: 1");
            System.out.println(fileName+ " is saved successfully");
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println("Status: 0");
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                reader.close();
                inputStream.close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                System.err.println("Error closing connection\n" + ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }   
    }
```

I think windows 10 firewall blocks connection, but I am not sure.

Comment: What does it mean: "It stops at the line"? The program just freezes, or do you get an exception? In the latter case,  we would like to see that exception together with the full stacktrace.

Comment: Yes it freezes and does not print any exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was the firewall blocking connection from the raspberry pi